# how can I download old packages( android 5.0) on sdk manager of Android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am using eclipse all the time. I want to study android studio , and  downloaded android studio and sdk. When I run the sdk manager , only android 7.0 was installed. The new sdk manager has a few differences. I don't know how to download android 5.0 packages?

[image]

Comment: SOLUTION:     Must set "SDK update sites" in Chinese.

The url I used is http://mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn/android/repository/

Must confirm that the label of  "Enabled"  is checked and it isn't a exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run sdk manager and you will see something like this:

[image]

You can check any android version you want here and by clicking apply and ok, it starts downloading.
If you don't want the whole package for each android version, you can click the `show package detail` checkbox on the button right of this window and see details of each package like below image:

[image]

Here you can check any subpackage you need and then click apply and ok.

It is also possible to copy and paste `platforms`, `build-tools` and other modules you need from your `eclipse sdk` to `android studio sdk`. Or set in your `android studio` preferences to use `eclipse sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

You should launch the standalone SDK manager to have access to available packages.
Your SDK path is `D:\Android\SDK`.

Use explorer to open that directory then launch `sdk manager.exe`.
Now you have access to available packages.

It is also possible using android studio itself. check `sdk tools` and `sdk update sites`. Available packages can be found there too.